# PHP regex not working with array string values

Tags: php, arrays, regex

i Have the following code, it works with single inputs but fails at  compound outputs.
The print array function confirms that the array values are correct. I don't know where the problem is.

Single Input:

```
1:10pm[Sat & Sun Only]
```

Compound Input:

```
10:35am, 12:40pm, 1:10pm[Sat & Sun Only]
```

Code excerpt is below:

```
function function1($input)
{
    $key1 = ', ';
    if (strpos($input, $key1) !== false) {
        $commas    = substr_count($input, $key1);
        $arraySize = $commas + 1;
        $result1   = explode($key1, $input);
    } else {
        $result1[0] = $input;
    }
    foreach ($result1 as $val) {
        if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}am\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found <br />";
        } else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}pm\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found 2<br />";
        } else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}am\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)-(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found 3<br />";
        } else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}pm\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun)-(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found 4<br />";
        } else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}am\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun) & (?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found 5<br />";
        } else if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}pm\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun) & (?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)) {
            echo "Match was found 6<br />";
        } else {
            echo 'Not found ';
        }
        //print $val;
    }
    print_r($result1);
}
$imran = '10:35am, 12:40pm, 1:10pm[Sat & Sun Only]';
function1($imran);
```

Comment: What is your expected output? I think your code can be optimized to just use one regexp. Also `function1` is a terrible name for a function. If you can't think of a good name for a function then that function is likely doing something very strange, or too many things.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? There's probably a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking the values in the array with the regular expressions. Here's what you have:

```
foreach($result1 as $val){
    if (preg_match('/^\d{1,2}.\d{2}am\[(?:Mon|Tues|Wed|Thurs|Fri|Sat|Sun).Only\]$/', $input)){
...
```

Notice that you're using `$input` in your call to `preg_match`. I think that should be `$val`.